# Show all sites, regardless if you are a member

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp-powershell

Currently I have a page which serves as a directory to SharePoint sites you have permission to access. It uses this query in PnP search: contentclass:STS_Site

This works just fine.

I'd also like to create a directory showing all our SharePoint sites, regardless of whether the user accessing has permission to see them.

So, if contentclass:STS_Site shows 10 sites you have access to, this new page will show 15 sites, 10 you have access to and 5 you don't. Just a normal list will be fine.

Does such a query exist?

Answer (score 0):

No, SharePoint Search/Microsoft Search API's are security trimmed to the user making the query. They would need to have at least some access to the sites, in order for search to return them to the user.

Comment: The List sites operation in Microsoft Graph supports application permissions, so this could be done using custom code. 

@AdamT312, if you're not familiar, application permissions is a technique used to give permissions to an application or a web part so it can perform tasks that the user running an application/web part may not have permission to do.

Comment: The question is about search though and search is security trimmed. Of course, if you're going down the application permissions and custom code route, the world is your oyster.